# java - how to make decision based on string

Tags: java, string, parsing, decision-tree

If you have a string like this `volume-7,notcontact-xxxx,not_lightlevel-1280.0,` and this string could vary with other options, like vibrate, light level, screen brightness etc...but the formatting would be the same...(setting-value,setting-value...)

What would be the best way to make a decision based on the current information you have on these settings? (i.e return true or false by checking the predefined string against the current contextual information I have)

So let's say you have the current contextual information...i.e the current volume level, vibrator setting, the light level, screen brightness, etc etc and you want to compare it against a pre-defined string such as the I wrote above,

how would you do it?

Would you parse the string and check for every single possibility? while doable, it doesn't sound very appealing..

Could I use decision trees? If yes, could someone tell me how I would go about it?

Thanks

Comment: I would try to think about the problem in terms of "real objects" and desired semantics: the strings above can merely be thought of as a [serialized] implementation (e.g. of a Map) detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing it into a `HashMap` would be my first thought.

You can also use a POJO if you know all the keys in advance. (You'll still have to populate the fields using reflection but you are guaranteed compile time type safety for all the other operations.)

(I might be completely misunderstanding your question, but I can't find any connection between the problem you described and decision trees.)

Comment: HashMap was my first thought as well but I will have to iterate through the map and check against each setting/value. What I'm essentially asking is if there's a cleverer way so that I can avoid all the if statements

Comment: @kkudi It depends on your comparison logic. Do you want to establish if setting A is equal to setting B? Or whether it is greater than the other? Do you have partial strings? If you do, do you simply ignore the keys that don't appear in the string?

Comment: @biziclop No. Each "setting" in the string is compared to its equivalent current setting. The string might not contain all the contextual information but only a subset. But since I don't know which "settings" the string is made up of, I'd have to check against every single one of them.

Comment: @kkudi You can simply iterate through the entries of the map and compare each one to the corresponding values of the other map. (`Map.keySet()` or `Map.entrySet()` being the relevant methods.) This way you don't need multiple `if` statements in your code.

Comment: @biziclop ah i never thought of it that way! so basically one of my maps would be 'statically' defined with all the settings and their respective current value. and the other one would be the map i get from the string i have